# Proposal to designate a canonical "how to modulate" post

Tags: discussion, duplicates, canonical-q-a

We get a significant number of "how to I modulate from X to Y" questions such as [Modulate from a minor to D major](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/132795/70803). I propose that these are all duplicates of [How many types of modulation are there?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/27079/70803).

My reasoning is that:

1. The techniques involved in (tonal) modulation are the same regardless of the particular start and end points.
2. Recommendations for specific modulations are all of equivalent value and opinion based, both of which are generally off-topic across SE sites.
3. If not duplicates, then we are in the position of fielding questions of modulation from and to every possible key/chord, all of which would have essentially the same answers, but with few, if any, as comprehensive as "How many types of modulation are there?". Thus, searching for a great answer would be luck-of-the-draw. This seems inefficient, if not absurd.

A loose sampling of relevant questions can be viewed by searching ["modulate from is:question"](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=modulate%20from%20is%3Aquestion). I am happy to do the more detailed research to suss out specific duplicates, but, as there are potentially a large number of affected posts, I'd like the community's weigh-in(s) before doing (or not doing) anything.

Comment: Sounds good, go for it

Comment: I agree, this would be good thing to do. I would however leave some of the duplicates available for future reference, i.e., not delete them. Some of them seem to provide examples that give a new insight or advice that some users may find useful that are out of the scope of [How many types of modulation are there?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/132795/70803) or that explore different techniques not directly related to the harmony. See for example @Laurence's answer in [Modulating from B major to A minor](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/54973/modulating-from-b-major-to-a-minor).

Comment: @GandalfTheBard Good point. I have no plans to vote for any deletions.

Answer (score 1):

After a week, there's a bit of support (2 upvotes and one comment) and no objections (no downvotes or negative comments). I'll give it another week, since Meta participation can take more time than the main site, and then I'll begin work.

Will post any updates here.

---

Update: I haven't forgotten about this and will start the process as soon as time allows.

---

#### Voted to close posts

- [How to modulate from Am to F#m?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/133488/70803)
- [With what chords do we modulate from Em to G?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/96149/70803)
- [modulating from G major to G# major](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/58750/70803)
- [How to modulate from e Phrygian to c minor](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/129249/70803)
- [How to modulate from one mode to the next](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/61056/70803)
- [How to modulate very smoothly and stealthily from major to minor?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/76406/70803)
- [Whats the smoothest way to modulate in minor to a neighboring key?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/124669/70803)
- [How could you make a key change sound natural](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/113974/70803)
- [How is modulation to the dominant achieved?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/127249/70803)

#### Closed posts

- [Modulating a minor 3rd [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/115440/70803)
- [Modulate from A minor to D major [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/132795/70803)
- [Modulating from key Gm to key Bbm [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/42649/70803)
- [How to smoothly modulate from A# minor to B minor [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/92111/70803)
- [Modulating from E Minor to C Minor [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/37827/70803)
- [Modulating from B major to A minor [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/54973/70803)
- [Ways to modulate from Lydian to the relative Mixolydian [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/57596/70803)
- [How to modulate from minor to parallel major [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/73671/70803)
- [Beginner needs help with simple modulation from Em to Am [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/103440/70803)
- [How to make a chord progress go from the key of C major to the key of A minor? [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/23382/70803)
- [How to modulate Phrygian to Harmonic Minor? [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/111708/70803)
- [What are some techniques for changing scale convincingly? [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/115704/70803)
- [How to modulate from A minor to C minor? [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/133578/70803)

Answer (score 0):

It just now occurred to me to check here on music.meta after seeing a few modulation questions closed as duplicates of [How many types of modulation are there?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/27079/70803).

I guess it's not the worst place to send them, but I wonder (and maybe this needs to be a question on the main music stack):

That question's community wiki answer is based on "Modulation Types for Musical Analysis" by Edward Murphy, Ph.D., The University of Arizona with
Revisions and Finale® Notation by Charles Leinberger, Ph.D., The University of Texas at El Paso.

Is this list of modulation types truly exhaustive?  Is it the only widely-published system of classifying modulations?

Comment: Should it be incomplete, that thread would still be the place to post an update, rather than techniques be spread out arbitrarily among various posts.